# Using < & > (less than and greater than) in an if statement in Jython

Tags: if-statement, jython

I'm writing a small program that requires a few **if** statements like so:

```
number=x/(y*y)

if number <5:
  print "blahblahblah"

if number >5 or <10:
  print "blahblahblah"

if number >10.5 or >15.0:
  print "blahblahblah"

if number >15:
  print "blahblahblah"
```

Basically I'm having trouble with using both > and < in my if statement and can't work out how to say "if less than 4 or more than 5"

When I load the program I get the following error -

> Invalid syntax
>   Your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal jython.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Realize that "if >5 or <10" will *always* be true...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
if number > 10 and number < 20 then:
   print "Number between 10 and 20"
```

Each comparison is an independent expression, combined together with `and`, `or`, etc.

Comment: that conditional is wrong. It will always return true.

Comment: I assume you meant `if number > 10 and number < 20 then` to demonstrate that you must specify the number in both places.

Comment: yeah yeah yeah. :p quick typing FTL.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Paul answer with `or`, `and` etc you can use `if 5 < number < 10:`:

```
if number < 5:
    print("a")

if 5 < number < 10:
    print("b")

if 10 < number < 15:
    print("c")

if number > 15:
    print("d")
```

You can also use `elif` (short of `else if`) and `else` which I prefer:

```
if number < 5:
    print("a")
elif number < 10:
    print("b")
elif number < 15:
    print("c")
else:
    print("d")
```

BTW in your code you used `or` instead of `and`.